# nhibernate left join linq

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I understand that nhibernate 3.1 does not support left join with the linq syntax and we have to use hql.

But does someone know if that feature is planned ? and when ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use HQL, you could also use QueryOver, if you are looking for intellisense support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently no details about that feature

A little example of Left join in HQL :

```
        var hql = @"select c.IdClient as IdClient, c.Denomination As Denomination, g.IdGriffe as IdGriffe
                    from Client c
                    left outer join c.GriffeClient gc
                    left outer join gc.Griffe g
                    with g.IdGriffe = :id
                    order by c.Denomination";

        var retour = session.CreateQuery(hql)
                .SetInt32("id", id)
                .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer())
                .List();
```

Regards